VSCode Dev Container not mounting source code folder
I'm trying to use Dev Containers on Fedora with regular Docker. When I Reopen in container none of the files in the workspace are visible.
I'm using one of the templates from microsoft (I've tried many), and all of the documentation suggests that the container workspace should mirror the local one.
Is this incorrect? What might I be doing wrong?
